# Windows 10: Can't enable Developer Mode since this setting is managed by my organization

Tags: windows, powershell

Recently I came across a problem. I'm trying to enable my Developer Mode, unfortunately, my organization doesn't allow it.

First of all, this is a personal computer and is not bound to any organizations.
Currently, I tried several things.

- Edit certain settings in my Group Policy (telemetry etc.
- Execute PowerShell commands to obtain Developer Mode
- Edit the Registry

I cant find anything specifically related to my problem, only about Windows Updates, which isn't what I am looking for.

I remember I found a PowerShell command to enable Developer mode. It worked (it was still blocked although the slider was 'On'), but it didn't stay and I can't retrieve the command.

If anyone could explain how I could get rid of the organization message, I'd be glad to hear it.

[Image about the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09x4F.png)

Comment: The “managed by your organization” appears when you have disabled a required feature necessary to do so or when it’s actually being managed by an organization

Comment: [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/some-settings-are-hidden-or-managed-by-your/8dffa2d5-0196-4737-81b6-cb45cc77eed2) is the solution to your problem.  If that still doesn’t solve the problem then you have [enabled](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/128943-cannot-turn-off-developer-mode-managed-your-organization.html) the group policy.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
It helps me:

- Open Edit group policy
- Go to Administrative Templates
- Open Windows Components
- Open App Package Deployment
- Allow all trusted apps to install (If it's already enabled - disable it, and enable again)

Like on this image: [The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsYf2.png)